# Best way to implement Day View / Schedule Android UI

Tags: android, user-interface, grid, android-relativelayout, schedule

> (disclaimer: all my life I've been incredibly far from UIs of any
>   type, shape or form - backend and algorithms were my things, and UX,
>   unfortunately, wasn't. But there's always a moment when you want to
>   give it a go...)

I've been fiddling with an idea of a toy project for myself, and as a part of it, I want to implement something similar to Schedule/Day view in Android calendar. Probably best this is explained by this UI mock (admittedly I'm not the best UI designer, but hopefully this would be enough to illustrate my point)

[image: UI mock]

Currently I'm thinking of using RelativeLayout to layout the schedule blocks and redraw background with the grid (hour lines). I fiddled a little bit with RelativeLayout and arguably this might do the trick, but I'm very unsure about the background. Do you think this approach would work? Is there some better way of doing it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wondering what features of a `RelativeLayout` you're thinking about leveraging? I recently created a UI similar to your mockup, but extended a plain `ViewGroup`. I'm guessing that you'll probably end up measuring and positioning the different elements (blocks, lines etc.) yourself, requiring a fine-grained control on what ends up where, especially if you're going to have different column widths and overlapping (in terms of time, not necessarily visually) events.

Comment: I can totally go for extending ViewGroup - do you have your code open-sourced somewhere so I can -copy/paste-^W^W get inspiration out of it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the code is open source, as we developed it for a client on request. Not sure it would help you a lot either, because it's relatively tightly coupled with a library we developed in-house. I'm happy to give general pointers or answer specific question to my best knowledge. Basically it's all about laying out the events correctly and calculating their bounds in a smart way to get the 'column spanning' effect.

Comment: OK I guess I'll give it a go and see how it works. If I realise I'm stuck I'll come back with questions here. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing, and could find no good options, so I created the [yadview](http://code.google.com/p/yadview/) project (https://code.google.com/p/yadview). yadview is a fork of the DayView schedule in the AOSP Calendar app, but has been reworked significantly to allow for integration into your application.

Sample screenshot of this View in an Activity:
[image]

Comment: How do I limit the number of pages.I want to show daily events on a page for the past seven days.How do I limit that using YadView?The pages keep swiping infinitely.Please help.

Comment: how to add new event by click?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project very similar to this! The idea is to have a sense of priority to the items. That way, the user can collapse the views into a single executable list of tasks, not worrying about the things that are lower priority until they need to cancel the higher priority events, at which point, the lesser priority events seamlessly fill in the blank space. Feel free to message me directly, as I'm sure there aren't many who would find our conversations helpful.